# What does a number of cores of "~2, bursted" mean?

Tags: travis-ci

According to [the docs](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/ci-environment/#Virtualization-environments) the sudo-enabled environment offers "~2" cores, "bursted". I don't understand what that is supposed to mean.

I think there's a hint in [this blog post](https://blog.travis-ci.com/2014-12-17-faster-builds-with-container-based-infrastructure/):

> The build containers in our legacy build infrastructure have had 1.5 cores (with burst capacity)

Sadly I don't know what "burst capacity" is.

I have asked this question before [on the Travis CI issue tracker](https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/6191) but since I got no answer I hope that I may find one here.

Comment: Update: in 2020, the link redirects to https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/reference/overview/ which simply states "2 cores" for all OSes.

Answer (score 9):

I'm not familiar with Travis, so I'll just explain what it usually means when you're allowed to burst the guaranteed CPU time in a container.

This is usually used to mean that you always have 2 cores available but you may get more CPU time for a short time. In particular, you're allowed to use CPU time not consumed by others. For instance, if someone on the host only uses 1.5 of the 2 available cores, the 0.5 unused cores become available to the others on the same host.

Comment: Thanks! I have some difficulty imagining what it means to use only 1.5 cores. A "core" in this context is pretty much a measure of CPU time, right? Is there any connection to the number of available "virtual CPU cores" that can execute code in parallel?

Comment: Also, would having "1.5 cores (with burst capacity)" be consistent with the description "~2 cores, bursted"? I.e. could having "~2, bursted" mean that sometimes, you might get less than 2 cores?

Comment: question 2: The ~ probably indicates that the 2 available cores is an approximation. It's hard to know for sure, only the operators of Travis can tell you for sure. My guess is that it is indeed possible that you have less than two cores available for a short time.

Comment: question 1: Yes, CPU cores relate to CPU time. If have 1.5 CPU available it mains you got 1.5 seconds processing time per second. So you may get 0.5 s on the first CPU, 0.4 s on the second and 0.6 s on the first (=1.5s in total).

Comment: Thank you for your explanations! I'll wait to see if anyone comes along with more specific knowledge about Travis. Otherwise the bounty is yours!

Comment: Travis simply uses either Docker (without sudo) or kvm or xen images (with sudo). So generally any kvm/xen answer on CPU scheduling will help you.
Travis runs on Amazon EC2, MacStadium, and Google Compute Engine.